# how to make take two lists and remove elements based on another list?

Tags: python, list

I have three lists.
Two lists of string, and one list of float. I used zip to match one list of string and float together that are the same length to make a new string. Basically:

```
letters1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
numbers = [0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 10.0, 28.0]
letters2 = ['a', 'c', 'e']
letnum = [i for i in zip(letters1, numbers)]
```

This gets me:
`[('a', 0.0), ('b', 3.0), ('c', 5.0), ('d', 10.0), ('e', 28.0)]`

I want to use the other list to get only `[0.0, 5.0, 28.0]`, but I don't know how to return a list of float like that.

I tried using `[x for x in letnum if x in letters2]` but that gave me `[]`.

I also know `letnum = [i for _, i in zip(letters1, numbers)]` will get me `[0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 10.0, 28.0]` but I don't know if that does anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try the following:

```
letters1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
numbers = [0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 10.0, 28.0]
letters2 = ['a', 'c', 'e']

d = {}
for i in range(len(letters1)):
    d[letters1[i]] = numbers[i]
letnum = [d[x] for x in letters2]
print(letnum)
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 5.0, 28.0]
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you for pointing to me to the thread. It is a difficult discussion to reach a conclusion. I suppose the restriction of the deletions/undeletions is one idea. BTW the listed guys are not the only ones who excessively delete questions, as you know.

Answer (score 3):

Each element in `letnum` is a tuple which is a pair of a letter and a float.
If you take the first element of the tuple and then check for existence in the `letters2` list you will find a match.

```
[x for x in letnum if x[0] in letters2]
```

`x[0]` is taking the first element of the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

If you anticipate large lists, here's a linear solution using a lookup dictionary to enable grabbing a float for each element in `letters2` in constant time instead of repeatedly iterating in a nested loop. Total time complexity is `O(len(letters) + len(letters2))` which is optimal:

```
>>> letters1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> numbers = [0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 10.0, 28.0]
>>> letters2 = ['a', 'c', 'e']
>>> lookup = {x: y for x, y in zip(letters1, numbers)}
>>> [lookup[x] for x in letters2 if x in lookup]
[0.0, 5.0, 28.0]
```

The reason your original attempt doesn't work is `[x for x in letnum if x in letters2]` tries to find a whole tuple `x` in `letters2` which only contains strings.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the entire process at once (edited slightly because I misunderstood the requirement)

`for` each of the `letter` and `number` pairs that we get by `zip`ping together `letters1` and `numbers`, we want: the `number`, but only `if` the `letter` was `in letters2`.

So, we write it exactly like that, except that the element description goes at the front.

```
[number for letter, number in zip(letters1, numbers) if letter in letter2]
```

---

To cover your attempts:

> I tried using `[x for x in letnum if x in letters2]` but that gave me `[]`.

Yes, because `x` is one of the pairs, and `letters2` doesn't contain those pairs. You can fix this as in @vaichidrewar's answer by extracting the letter, `x[0]`, for the comparison. Similarly, `x` is one of the pairs, and you only want the number, so `x[1]` extracts the number.

> I also know letnum = [i for _, i in zip(letters1, numbers)] will get me [0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 10.0, 28.0] but I don't know if that does anything.

It's a start, in the sense that you are using *unpacking* for the `zip` results to give separate names to the elements of each pair that you get. By convention, we use `_` to refer to values that we don't care about; but you do care about both values (because you want the letter for the condition).

Answer (score 0):

convert `zip object` into `list` and access `0, 2, 5` index using `range(0, len(numbers), 2)`

```
letters1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
numbers = [0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 10.0, 28.0]
letters2 = ['a', 'c', 'e']
letnum = [list(zip(letters1, numbers))[i] for i in range(0,len(numbers), 2)]

print(letnum)
```

---

**Methiod-2**

```
letnum = [i for i in zip(letters1, numbers) if i[0] in letters2]
```